# Why are 2 users logged into my mac os x when I type command 'w' on the terminal?

Tags: macos, unix

Here is a [Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn6XQ.png). I am studying UNIX and I have learned about the `w` command. When I type `w` on terminal, it is printing "2 users".

I am the only user of my MacBook.

Comment: I thibk your question is off-topic on stack overflow. Better try http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it doesen't mean that two users are logged in. Its the same user as you can see both have the same user in the first column. however it shows different sessions.

1. the first one is you logged into the graphical environment (the console) of OS X.
2. The second line is the terminal you have open where you am running the "w"command. that is why in the last column it shows "w"

> The w command Show who is logged on and what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is two users logged. But logged doesn't mean that you obtain a session by typing logname and password. You are considered as logged for each controlling session you possess, when some process controls a terminal (see column tty) and is a session leader.

When you entered the graphic session a record has been stored and that session controls the `console`. When you opened a terminal another session has been created controlling some terminal and that stored another record to the login database. Try to open another terminal and observe that you are logged three times. Experiment with user switching, etc.

If you need some more information, read about Unix process group, sessions, terminal control, login shell, but be aware that is very technical and hard to understand in the many details.

Comment: Thank you for answer me, I check it now. Thank you.